# How to add a certain value to anchor tag?

Tags: jquery, tags, jquery-animate, href

I have the following code

```
<a href="" (set value 1)>Inside Link which sets a value</a>

<script>
$(a).click(function() {
    i=value of a tag;
    $('#square').animate({'left': i * 360});
});

</script>
```

And i want to add a value attribute to an anchor tag. How to do it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you want to add a random attribute for a value, you can use data attributes:

```
<a href="#" data-value="1">Text</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("a").click(function(){
    i=$(this).data("value");
    $('#square').animate({'left': i * 360});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are using HTML5 you can use the `data-` technique.

```
<a id="target" href="http://foo.bar" data-custom-value="1">Text</a>

$("#target").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).data("custom-value");
    // do other stuff.
});
```

**EDIT**

Usage of `.data` instead of `.attr` is more appropriate

Comment: @gdoron I was going to mention that, but then I looked around jQuery's documentation a bit, and they say there is no problem with `.attr("data-custom-value")`, `.data()` is only encouraged when you also will be setting values for it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use custom data attributes see [this](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) .

```
<a href="#" data-json="{ 'myValue':'1'}">Click</a> //you can even pass multiple values there.
```

then access it using data() function.

Or instead of using json you can put it as an attribute :

```
<a href="link"  myvalue="1"">
```

then get it using :

```
$("#link").data("myvalue")
```

Answer (score 1):

`<a href="#" data-value="IE" id="click">Click</a>`

```
    ` $("#click").click(function(event){console.log($(this).data("value"));});`
```

Answer (score 1):

data-value is a good attribute. but..
You can also add a " rel " attribute to your anchor tag.
it describes the relation to the document where the link points to. And you can also use it to store a value.

Like This -

```
$("a").click(function(){
 var page = $(this).attr('rel'); // save the attribute value here

 sessionStorage.setItem("text",page);

/*save it in session storage if you want to send (or retrieve) this value to another page. 
if not then use it easily without saving it in session storage*/

 //Use it here 

 return false; // to stop the redirection if <a> contains a link
});
```

Comment: how to set the value for rel in ??? below if I have something like this.
function (value) {
 return <a class="btn-export" rel=???>Export</a>
}